# References in TOC on chapter level

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

I use biblatex to handle my references. I'm adding the bibliography to the TOC by using the following line:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literatur}]
```

Now the bibliography is a section below the last chapter in my book. How can I change that so that the bibliography becomes an unnumbered chapter on its own?

Best regards...

Comment: By default `\printbibliography` is a `\chapter*` in classes that support chapters (`book`- and `report`-like classes) and a `\section*` in classes that don't support chapters (`article`-like classes). This is even the case with `heading=bibintoc,` as that only influences whether or not the bibliography goes to the ToC. See for example https://gist.github.com/moewew/4a83050f5ebd03493e057f70d163b625. If that isn't the case, something unusual is going on in your document and we need to know more about it to be able to help. ...

Comment: ... Please show us a short example document that reproduces the behaviour you are describing with as little code as possible (if you like you can use the example I posted above as a basis): This is often called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and crucial with issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as my problem had something to do with the Springer Latex Style svmono is ws using. I switched to scrbook now and averything works like a charm.